# regex - don't allow name to finish with hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex using javascript that will allow names like `abc-def` but will not allow `abc-`
(hyphen is also the only nonalpha character allowed)

The name has to be a minimum of 2 characters. I started with
`^[a-zA-Z-]{2,}$`, but it's not good enough so I'm trying something like this
`^([A-Za-z]{2,})+(-[A-Za-z]+)*$`.

It can have more than one `-` in a name but it should never start or finish with `-`.

It's allowing names like `xx-x` but not names like `x-x`. I'd like to achieve that `x-x` is also accepted but not `x-`.

Thanks!

Comment: What about `-xxx` ? Should they be accepted? Also, can there be more than a single `-`, e.g. `abc-def-ghi` ?

Comment: good point, thanks! no, starting with -xx shouldn't be accepted but we can have more than one - abc-def-ghi (just not start or finish with -)

Comment: Is `aa` (no `-`) acceptable?

Comment: yes, as long as there's more than 1 character.

Comment: What about multiple successive hyphens?  `x------y`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Option 1

This option matches strings that begin and end with a letter and ensures two `-` are not consecutive so a string like `a--a` is invalid. To allow this case, see the **Option 2**.

```
^[a-z]+(?:-?[a-z]+)+$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[a-z]+` Match any lowercase ASCII letter one or more times (with `i` flag this also matches uppercase variants)
- `(?:-?[a-z]+)+` Match the following one or more times

  - `-?` Optionally match `-`
  - `[a-z]+` Match any ASCII letter (with `i` flag)
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

```js
var a = [
  "aa","a-a","a-a-a","aa-aa-aa","aa-a", // valid
  "aa-a-","a","a-","-a","a--a" // invalid
]
var r = /^[a-z]+(?:-?[a-z]+)+$/i

a.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(`${s}: ${r.test(s)}`)
})
```

---

#### Option 2

If you want to match strings like `a--a` then you can instead use the following regex:

```
^[a-z]+[a-z-]*[a-z]+$
```

```js
var a = [
  "aa","a-a","a-a-a","aa-aa-aa","aa-a","a--a", // valid
  "aa-a-","a","a-","-a" // invalid
]
var r = /^[a-z]+[a-z-]*[a-z]+$/i

a.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(`${s}: ${r.test(s)}`)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
/(?!.*-$)^[a-z][a-z-]+$/i
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/OGHDkl/4)

**Breakdown:**

```
// Negative lookahead so that it can't end with a -
(?!.*-$)

// The actual string must begin with a letter a-z
[a-z]

// Any following strings can be a-z or -, there must be at least 1 of these
[a-z-]+
```

```js
let regex = /(?!.*-$)^[a-z][a-z-]+$/i;

let test = [
  'xx-x',
  'x-x',
  'x-x-x',
  'x-',
  'x-x-x-',
  '-x',
  'x'
];

test.forEach(string => {
  console.log(string, ':', regex.test(string));
});
```

Comment: No need to use `(?!^-)` with `[a-z-]{2,}`. Just use `[a-z][a-z-]+` instead. It saves steps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first  assertion accepts 2 or more [A-Za-z]. You will need to modify it to accept one or more character:

```
^[A-Za-z]+((-[A-Za-z]{1,})+)?$
```

**Edit:** solved some commented issues

```
/^[A-Za-z]+((-[A-Za-z]{1,})+)?$/.test('xggg-dfe'); // Logs true
/^[A-Za-z]+((-[A-Za-z]{1,})+)?$/.test('x-d'); // Logs true
/^[A-Za-z]+((-[A-Za-z]{1,})+)?$/.test('xggg-'); // Logs false
```

**Edit 2:** Edited to accept characters only

```
/^[A-Za-z]+((-[A-Za-z]{1,})+)?$/.test('abc'); // Logs true
```

Comment: this will accept one character only e.g. a
the name should be at least 2 characters long so this won't work.

Comment: I just improved it, while doing some tests, now it works perfectly

Comment: ab doesn't pass and it should

Comment: Improved to match also simple strings. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want to accept such as `A---A` as well :

```
^(?!-|.*-$)[A-Za-z-]{2,}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/4UYd9l/4/

If you don't want to accept  such as `A---A` do this:

```
^(?!-|.*[-]{2,}.*|.*-$)[A-Za-z-]{2,}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/qH4Q0q/4/

So both will accept only word starting from two characters of the pattern `[A-Za-z-]` and not start or end `(?!-|.*-$)` (negative lookahead) with `-` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this `/([a-zA-Z]{1,}-[a-zA-Z]{1,})/g`

Comment: unfortunately, it allows name like -a-a

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following :

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z]$
```

It validates :

- that the matched string is at least composed of two characters (the first and last character classes are matched exactly once)
- that the first and the last characters aren't dashes (the first and last character classes do not include `-`)
- that the string can contain dashes and be greater than 2 characters (the second character class includes dashes and will consume as much characters as needed, dashes included).

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/tdvntz/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=[A-Za-z](?:-|[A-Za-z]))(?:(?:-|^)[A-Za-z]+)+$
```

Asserts that

- the first character is a-z
- the second is a-z or hyphen

If this matches

- looks for groups of one or more letters prefixed by a hyphen or start of string, all the way to end of string.

You can also use the I switch to make it case insensitive.