# regex pattern not working properly in iOS

Tags: regex

I'm doing client side validation for a website and there's this bug...

Using this regex: `/^(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,20}(?<!-)$/`

I'm trying to block special characters from being used in the input field.

This is working for all devices except iOS.  Why would this be the case?  Is my regex not solid?

Comment: Your pattern prevents matching `-` at the start and at the end, is that the expected?

Comment: Include the code you're using the regex in.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/AJxEGL/1

Comment: @Aaron that's true, so `^(?!-)[a-zA-Z\d-]{0,19}[^\W_]$` (removed my other comment)

Comment: The [answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49738357/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookbehind support has only been recently added to the regex engines of various browsers, and Safari for iOS hasn't followed suit yet, which means that `(?<!-)` is a syntax error.

You can check the [MDN's compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility), the row "lookbehind assertions ((?<= ) and (?<! ))" states that the feature is still not available for a few browsers, including iOS's Safari (although I'm not sure it's quite up-to-date as I believe up-to-date versions of Firefox do handle lookbehinds; it mentions a bug though, which might mean the implementation is present but incorrect).

I suggest you use the following regex instead for the same effect, more portability and a very slight increase in performances :

```
/^(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,19}[a-zA-Z0-9]$/
```

The second character class matches an alphanumeric character and is sufficient to make sure that 1) the string doesn't end in a dash and 2) the string is at least one character long. The start of the regex is changed to make sure that it can match 0 characters and at most 19 in order for the whole match to vary between 1 and 20 characters, it is otherwise left untouched.