# Regex for detecting tagged @users

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

I am making an app where if a user has "@username" in a text, it tags them and sends notification.
I tried to doing this by using this regex `/\B(\@[a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!;)/` this works but I dont want it to consider it valid when there is more than one "@".
For example:

@username - valid

@@username - invalid

hey @username - valid

@usern@name - invalid

hey@username - invalid

Comment: @decpk but it doesnt return valid when i do `hey @username`

Comment: Might suffice: [`(?:\s|^)@[a-zA-Z]+(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/gGugJm/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<=\s|^\s?)@[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s|\s?$)` might work.

```js
const testcase = ['@username', '@@username', 'hey @username', '@usern@name', 'hey@username', 'hey @username hey', '@username hey'];

testcase.forEach(text => {
    console.log(text + ' => ' + 
        /(?<=\s|^\s?)@[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s|\s?$)/.test(text)
    );
});
```

Comment: You can shorten the pattern to `(?<!\S)@[a-zA-Z]+(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/ZaOChf/1

Comment: @The fourth bird yes, a good usage on negative of negative

Comment: this regex don't work on iOs !
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526540/regex-pattern-not-working-properly-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `^@[a-z]+$`

[image]

```js
function isValid(str) {
  const regex = /^@[a-z]+$/;
  return str.split(" ").some((s) => regex.test(s));
}

console.log(isValid("@username"))
console.log(isValid("hey @username"))
console.log(isValid("@@username"))
console.log(isValid("@usern@name"))
console.log(isValid("hey@username"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex that will help you acheive the task you want -

```
^@[A-z0-9_-.]+$
```

Assuming that you will also encounter usernames such as -

@user.name

@user-name

@user_name

@user.name.

@User_name

Comment: thank you but I edited the question. i want it to return as valid if the string is "hey @username"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, as per my understanding regexes are used for finding strings or replacing strings on a pattern. If you want to return "valid" at a username, you can put that in a if statement, if regex pattern is found then it is valid, else not valid.